# Calculate the sum of the values of the selected cells in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I come back again with my problems. I am just a beginner who learns the Java code.

I have a `JTable` allowing me to display data from my database. I want to perform calculations on several cells (by selecting the line) of the table.

I want to be able to add or decrease the target cell value depending on whether a line is selected or deselected in my table.

To achieve this, I created a variable allowing me to store the sum of the values ​​of the selected cells. Then, I used the `MouseEvent` to listen to the click on a line. Finally I get the value of the selected line (target cell) by the `getValuesAt()` method.

Currently, this code allows me to sum up by clicking on a line. But he only counts the selected lines; rather, it is the sum of the existing value with the new selection. I do not know how to write the code allowing me only selected lines.

Here is my code:

To display the data:

```
public void remplirTableau(){
    MetierImpl metier=new MetierImpl();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String codeCli=cmbCodeCli.getSelectedItem().toString();
    List<Echeancier> opss=metier.consulterEcheancierNonRembourser(codeCli);
    model = new DefaultTableModel(){
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int iRowIndex, int iColumnIndex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex==1 || columnIndex==2 || columnIndex==3) {
                return Object.class; // le type des données de la première colonne
            }else{
                return Double.class;
            }
        }
    };
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"Ref","Date prévu","Date réalisé","Dégré","Capital","Amortis","Interet","Epargne","Echeance"});
    Object[] row = new Object[9];

    for(Echeancier cl:opss){ 
        row[0] = cl.getIdEch();
        row[1] = sdf.format(cl.getDateEch());
        if(cl.getDateR()!=null){
            row[2] = sdf.format(cl.getDateR());
        }else{
            row[2] = cl.getDateR();
        }
        row[3] = cl.getNumEch();
        row[4] = cl.getCapital();
        row[5] = cl.getAmorti();
        row[6] = cl.getInteret();
        row[7] = cl.getEpargne();
        row[8] = cl.getEcheance();

        model.addRow(row);
    }
    table.setModel(model);
}
```

To listen to clicks and do the math:

```
private double valeur=0;
private void maybeShowPopup(MouseEvent e) {
    int row=table.getSelectedRow();
    MetierImpl metier=new MetierImpl();
    //double valeur=0;
    try {
        if (e.getClickCount()==1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
                valeur+=(double)(table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 5));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(valeur);
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Veuillez selectionné la ligne concernée.");
    }
}
```

At the `JTable` I did this:

```
table = new JTable();
/**
* Cette action permet de faire une action sur un Jtable
*/
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        maybeShowPopup(e);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        maybeShowPopup(e);
    }
});
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Instead of adding a mouse listener add `table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener()`. In the listener you can get `table.getSelectedRows()` and perform your summing.

Answer (score 0):

about my problem in summary I try to sum the values of the selected boxes in a JTable. If I click on the first box, only its value is displayed. if I click on a second box that its value is added to the value of the first one so on. On the other hand, if I deselect a box, its value decreases in the existing total.
I want a can like for Excel.